# Get date a user changed the plan they are on in Stripe using Flask

Tags: python, stripe-payments

Working with Stripe and trying to set some basic info into the metadata field. I have two plans created, a paid and free. The free plan is used when a customer cancels.
 Many of these customers have been changed through Stripe Dashboard already so using a webhook will not work.

With this code I am able to get all customers on a specific plan and show that in metadata. The problem is that the .created date gives me the date the customer was created and not the date the plan was changed.
 If I change the plan in dashboard by adding a new plan and deleting the old one (from that customer) I can use the time the old plan was unsubscribed. But the option in the dashboard to change plan does something different and there is no unsubscribe. 
 My app is a connected account creating charges on other stripe accounts that have a dashboard of their own, so just not using the change plan button is not an option.
 Here is the code that gets the plan and created date.

```
canceled=stripe.Subscription.list(
plan='plan_Elm8GW7mwgDj5S',
stripe_account=stripe_keys['acct_num'],
)
for cancel in canceled.auto_paging_iter():


    customer_id=cancel.customer
    cd=cancel.created
    canceled_date=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(cd).strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
    stripe.Customer.modify(
    customer_id,
    stripe_account=stripe_keys['acct_num'],
    metadata={'Status': 'Canceled',
    'Canceled On': canceled_date}

    )
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the API to [list events](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/list?lang=python). You can specify the `type` of event to retrieve just those events, and look at the creation time of the event to know when it occurred.

It sounds like you want to focus on the [customer.subscription.created](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types?lang=python#event_types-customer.subscription.created) event and then look at those events for subscriptions using the free plan. There are also other `customer.subscription.*` events for updates, deletions, and trials ending.

Comment: thank you for your time. From what I have read, to use events would require a webhook to obtain the event ID. Many of our customers have already been changed and I belive a webhook will not work.

Comment: A webhook is just involved with getting alerted of new events -- each event causes a webhook notification to be fired. Any time after that, you can use the Events API to retrieve those events (without a webhook being involved).

Think of `event` as the actual object in the Stripe API, and a webhook as a way that you can be notified of those events. The `event` still exists perpetually long after the webhook was involved.

Comment: Ok so when I re-read your answer, I think there is something simple that I am just not connecting. Please excuse my ignorance, I am a beginner, but I believe that your solution is what I am using currently. The issue I am running into with the customer.subscription.created , is that it is giving me the date the customer signed up to the original plan. Not the new one. Also when the stripe dash is used to change the plan it is not changing at all. I believe the reason is that the Stripe API is changing the plan and not the actual subscription

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. Are you reusing the same subscription but changing the plan on it, or are you deleting the existing subscription and creating a new subscription with the new plan?

Comment: That is the exact issue! So when I was testing I was deleting one and adding a new. Then when I built out for the API I did the same. delete old sub and add new one. customer.subscription.created  was working fine. Then one of the companies found an "easier" way to switch them in there stripe dashboard. That method did whatever Stripe does, I believe just changed the plan and now the db is kind of a mess lol. I was hoping for a way to find just the plan change and not rely on he created but no luck so far

Comment: It sounds like you may be [changing the plan on the existing subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrading-downgrading) and if that's the case, you want to instead check the time of any events with the type of [customer.subscription.updated](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-customer.subscription.updated). The timing of those events will tell you when the actual change of plans occurred.

Comment: I am going to mark this answer as correct with a caveat for any future readers. As per Stripes documentation, they recommend changing a customer to a free plan or giving a discount. This was the method I was using and it was also creating the problem with getting a cancel date. But this was not the worst problem. Stripe was still billing the paused customers every week for $0. This is a bad UI and we quickly decided to just cancel the customer and use this answer to get the date.